# Haskell - How to concatenate a String to a list of Strings

Tags: string, list, haskell, ghci

I have a list of Strings and I am trying to add a String at the end of the list in the following code but I am getting type matching errors:

```
eliminateImpl :: [String] -> String -> [String]
eliminateImpl [] _ = []
eliminateImpl (p:ps) r = if (contains (p:ps) "Impl")
                         then if (p == "Impl" )
                              then "Not " ++r++" Or "++ps -- TRYING TO CONCATENATE HERE
                              else let r = r++p
                                   in eliminateImpl ps r
                          else (p:ps)

contains :: [String] -> String -> Bool
contains [_] [] = True
contains [] _ = False
contains (p:ps) c = if p == c
                    then True
                    else contains ps c
```

What the code actually does is that the function eleminateImpl takes a first order logic expression, for example: "eliminateImpl ["Q(y)","Impl","P(x)"] []" and it should remove the implication and modify the expression so that the output is: "eliminateImpl ["Not", "Q(y)"," Or ","P(x)"]

I tried r++p and r:p but both are not working. This is the error:

> Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’
>
> ```
> Expected type: [String]
>
>   Actual type: [Char]
>
> In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘"Not "’
>
> In the expression: "Not " ++ r ++ " Or " ++ ps
>
> In the expression:
>
>   if (p == "Impl") then
>
>       "Not " ++ r ++ " Or " ++ ps
>
>   else
>
>       let r = r ++ p in eliminateImpl ps r
> ```

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: What should the list of strings look like afterwards?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you wan't to do? I can't seem to make sense of what you have written.

Comment: @SebastianRedl The function should get a first order logic expression, for example: "eliminateImpl ["Q(y)","Impl","P(x)"] []" and the function should remove the implication and modify the expression so that the output is: "eliminateImpl ["Not", "Q(y)"," Or ","P(x)"]"

Comment: you want to replace ++ with : throughout this line

Comment: Should it replace all occurrences of "impl" or only one?

Comment: @user2008934 I am assuming for the moment it is only one for simplification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this seems to be close to what you want:

```
EliminateImpl :: [String] -> [String]
EliminateImpl [] = []
EliminateImpl [x] = [x]
EliminateImpl (pred:impl:rest) str
    | impl == "impl" = ("Not" : pred : "Or" : (EliminateImpl rest))
    | otherwise = (pred : (EliminateImpl (impl : rest)))
```

If I have misunderstood, please comment and I will change my answer.

To replace only one implication:

```
EliminateImpl :: [String] -> [String]
EliminateImpl [] = []
EliminateImpl [x] = [x]
EliminateImpl (pred:impl:rest) str
    | impl == "impl" = ("Not" : pred : "Or" : rest)
    | otherwise = (pred : (EliminateImpl (impl : rest)))
```

These functions should go through the list of Strings until they find the first `"impl"`.
Nothing before the `"impl"` will be changed. If you want to change this the modifications should be trivial.

Comment: Yes the logic is correct. There were only minor syntax problems with it that I fixed and now it works perfectly. I am confused though why after fixing the appending of the variables in my own code I got a stackOverflow problem but this one does not.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to replace the two terminating cases with a single `EliminateImpl xs = xs` case after the special case?

Comment: @SebastianRedl - Probably, I just don't think in that order, probably because of the way recursion works in imperative languages.

Answer (score 1):

Type annotations:

```
r :: String
p :: String
ps :: [String]
-- We need to produce a [String], not a String

(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
(++) :: String -> String -> String -- Because String = [Char]

(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]

"Not " ++ r ++ " Or " :: String
("Not " ++ r ++ " Or ") : ps :: [String]
```

This process should guide you to a correct implementation. Work through the types carefully. I like to use `let` or `where` to write in type annotations for intermediate values; that way I'll get a really specific type error when an expression doesn't have the type I expect.

Comment: I fixed it but now I got a "ERROR - C stack overflow". Any ideas why?

Comment: Also r is not a String, it is an [String] as well. But somehow this worked fine. Except for the Stackoverflow error.